# How to run a compiled Go test binary?

Tags: go, go-testing

I compiled a Go test library by running `go test -c ./model`. According to [Go docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go) it can be run using `go run -exec xprog` command, however, I keep getting errors while trying to run my generated `model.test` binary. What is the full command here?

P.S I know you can use a different flag to compile and run but this is not what I need.

Comment: "According to Go docs ..." Can you please provide a reference to the specific documentation you read?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the binary the same as any other. For example, in the shell:

```
./model.test
```

Test results will be written to the standard output, and the process exit code will be `0` if all tests passed.